# constructor threw exception nested exception is java.lang.nullpointerexception

Tags: java, spring

Hi following is the scenario

```
@Component   
public class DateFormatter() {

public String DateToString() {
   //some Logic; 
      }
    }

public class DataProvider{

@Resource("dateFormatter")
private DateFormatter dateFormatter;

public void test(){
  Date date = new Date();


    String formattedDate = this.dateFormatter(date);

  system.out.print("Formatted Date is :" + formattedDate);}
}
```

constructor threw exception nested exception is java.lang.nullpointerexception is what i see on my console

Comment: Is there no stacktrace?  it should tell you which constructor nullpointered.  Also, non of the code you posted here contains a constructor that could possibly nullpointer...

Comment: `public class DateFormatter() {`  is not compileable in the first place

Comment: Please format your code so that it's legible.

Comment: Exactly what I'm confused about also the DateFormatter is giving me null pointer

Comment: Please don't post sloppy code. If you need precise help, then be precise in your question and your code.

Answer (score 0):

`this.dateFormatter(date);` is calling DateFormatter and dateFormatter and it do not have method like this becouse dateFormatter in your example is not a method.

```
public String DateToString(Date date) {
    //some Logic;
    return "";
}
```

You can not call DateToString method with date in parameter and do not provide it in method declaration.

```
public class DataProvider{

        private DateFormatter dateFormatter;

        public void test(){
            Date date = new Date();

            DateFormatter dateFormatter = new DateFormatter();
            String formattedDate = dateFormatter.DateToString(date);

            System.out.print("Formatted Date is :" + formattedDate);}
    }
```

Or you can do something like this:
public class DataProvider{

```
    private DateFormatter dateFormatter;

    public DataProvider(DateFormatter dateFormatter) {
        this.dateFormatter = dateFormatter;
    }

    public void test(){
        Date date = new Date();

        String formattedDate = dateFormatter.DateToString(date);

        System.out.print("Formatted Date is :" + formattedDate);}
}
```

You have to create instance of a Object to call a method.

Comment: sorry it is this.dateFormatter.DateToString(date)